# Akka based Runnable Jar

Tags: java, eclipse, akka

I'm trying to run a runnable jar from a command line which has embedded in it several akka processes. 
Although I'm not the original author of the application I know that the code does run quite happily in an eclipse. 
However when I try to export and then run as a runnable Jar, then it falls over after a period of time and thats when its start to initiate the akka processes.
I am running it using Java 8

```
java -jar something.jar {options}
```

error:

```
   at akka.actor.ActorInitializationException$.apply(Actor.scala:174)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:607)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:461)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:483)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
    Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: ActorSystem [akka://ClusterSystem] needs to have a 'ClusterActorRefProvider' enabled in the configuration, currently uses [akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider]
    at akka.cluster.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.scala:71)
    at akka.cluster.Cluster$.createExtension(Cluster.scala:34)
    at akka.cluster.Cluster$.createExtension(Cluster.scala:29)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.registerExtension(ActorSystem.scala:737)
    at akka.actor.ExtensionId$class.apply(Extension.scala:79)
    at akka.cluster.Cluster$.apply(Cluster.scala:29)
    at akka.actor.ExtensionId$class.get(Extension.scala:91)
    at akka.cluster.Cluster$.get(Cluster.scala:30)
    at akka.cluster.Cluster.get(Cluster.scala)
    at com.dynniq.its.csm.core.akka.Actor.preStart(Actor.java:93)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:489)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundPreStart(UntypedActor.scala:95)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:590)

    @Override
    public void preStart() {
    **cluster = Cluster.get(getContext().system());**
    cluster.subscribe(getSelf(), MemberUp.class);
    preStartExtra();
    }
```

but as I say it seems to work in the eclipse environment.
what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the middle of the error message:

```
Caused by: akka.ConfigurationException: ActorSystem [akka://ClusterSystem] needs to have a 'ClusterActorRefProvider' enabled in the configuration, currently uses [akka.actor.LocalActorRefProvider]
```

A simple clustering config looks like this, note akka.actor.provider setting:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/cluster/cluster-usage-scala.html

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 0
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551", 
      "akka://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]

    auto-down = on
  }
}
```

The config is a bit different in the newer versions of Akka, see details in http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/cluster-usage.html

```
  actor {
    provider = "cluster"
  }
```

So your app either can't read the application.conf from resources for some reason or the configuration file is not properly passed as a parameter to java -jar

Comment: Indeed the question is where `akka.actor.provider` is set when running from eclipse, and why is that not carried over correctly when running from a jar. One other thing I can imagine is when you're setting this value in `reference.conf` instead of `application.conf`: because `reference.conf`'s are read from the classpath their order may not be defined, so you shouldn't have overlapping settings in `reference.conf` and instead put your main application configuration in `application.conf`.